# How to optimize my if else code c#

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I have this code below:

```
TryUpdateModel(model);
            if (ModelState.IsValid && model.FullNameIsChecked == true && model.LookingFor == null)
            {
                model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.UserId == user.Id);
                model.ContactList.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.FullName, y.FullName));
            }
            else if (ModelState.IsValid && model.FullNameIsChecked == false && model.LookingFor == null)
            {
                model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.UserId == user.Id);
                model.ContactList.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Email, y.Email));
            }
            else if (ModelState.IsValid && model.LookingFor != null && model.FullNameIsChecked == true)
            {
                model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.UserId == user.Id);
                model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.FullName.Contains(model.LookingFor));
                model.ContactList.OrderBy(f => f.FullName);
            }
            else if (ModelState.IsValid && model.LookingFor != null && model.FullNameIsChecked == false)
            {
                model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.UserId == user.Id);
                model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.Email.Contains(model.LookingFor));
                model.ContactList.OrderBy(e => e.Email);
            }
            else
            {
                model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.UserId == user.Id);
            }
```

I'm using .NET MVC 5 with Razor engine, and with code above i make sorting operations. Can i optimize my **If else** part of code? The only thing that is  on my mind is to use **switch - case operator** but it will look like almost similarly.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- i cant see any use in your code checking state for `ModelState`
- No need to compare bool in if condition,
   ie

  ```
  if(true)
  ```

  is same as

  ```
  if(bool variable=true)
  ```
- use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` to check `null`

  ```
   TryUpdateModel(model);

    model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.UserId == user.Id);

          if(  String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.LookingFor))
          {
              if(model.FullNameIsChecked)
              {
                  model.ContactList.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.FullName, y.FullName));
              }
              else
              {
                  model.ContactList.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Email, y.Email));
              }
          }
          else
          {
              if(model.FullNameIsChecked)
              {
                 model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.FullName.Contains(model.LookingFor));
                 model.ContactList.OrderBy(f => f.FullName);
              }
              else
              {
                 model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.UserId == user.Id);
                 model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.Email.Contains(model.LookingFor));
              }
          }
  ```

Comment: This is what i'm looking for. Maximum one If operator within If operator. Great answer. Thank you !

Comment: @StoyanPetkov but it unnesscesarily call `GetAll` twice, that can't be good.

Comment: @Jodrell Yes just noticed ,i didn't go inside his business logic,but definitely its need to be looked

Answer (score 2):

All your cases fit in this:

```
//Place this here since it's non conditional
model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.UserId == user.Id);


if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if(model.LookingFor == null)
    {
        if(model.FullNameIsChecked){
            //...
        }else
        {
            //...
        }
    }else
    {
        if(model.FullNameIsChecked){
            //...
        }else
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
else
{
    //... Actually you don't need this case...
}
```

Comment: You don't indicate that some code is non-conditional.

Comment: Thanks for help. The problem is that my mentor says it is bad practice to use more than once If operator within if operator... In other words he told me do not do like this: If () { if (){ if() { etc..} } }

Comment: @StoyanPetkov But expanding the nested conditionals is even worse.

Answer (score 1):

When `model.LookingFor` is non-null, you call `contactRepository.GetAll()` twice.  The first call, to `contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.UserId == user.Id)`, is superfluous, right?

Sometimes you call `.Sort()`, and other times you call `.OrderBy()`.  Why the inconsistency?

You've used `x`, `f`, and `e` as dummy variables.  I recommend using the some dummy variable consistently — perhaps `c` for "contact".

In any case, this code wants to do some kind of `GetAll()`, possibly followed by sorting.  So, let's write one call to `GetAll()` and one call to `OrderBy()`.

```
TryUpdateModel(model);
model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(filter:
    !ModelState.IsValid ?      (c => c.UserId == user.Id) :
    model.LookingFor == null ? (c => c.UserId == user.Id) :
    model.FullNameIsChecked ?  (c => c.FullName.Contains(model.LookingFor)) :
                               (c => c.Email.Contains(model.LookingFor))
);
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    model.ContactList.OrderBy(model.FullNameIsChecked ?
        (c => c.FullName) : (c => c.Email)
    );
}
```

Comment: contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.UserId == user.Id), is superfluous, right? No, its necessary. I have User that comprise a list of contacts. So the first time when i call contact.GetAll() i call it because i need to get contacts for current user. And if user want to sort his contacts Asc. i call .GetAll() second time so they will be displayed  sorted. I really like your improvement. I appreciate that. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

```
TryUpdateModel(model);
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
  model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.UserId == user.Id);
  if(model.LookingFor == null)
  {
        if(model.FullNameIsChecked)
        {
             model.ContactList.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.FullName, y.FullName));
        }
        else
        {
             model.ContactList.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Email, y.Email));
        }
  }
  else
  {
        if(model.FullNameIsChecked)
        {
            model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.FullName.Contains(model.LookingFor));
            model.ContactList.OrderBy(f => f.FullName);
        }
        else
        {
            model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.Email.Contains(model.LookingFor));
            model.ContactList.OrderBy(e => e.Email);
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not needed as the model state is not valid.

Comment: Thanks for help. The problem is that my mentor says it is bad practice to use more than once If operator within if operator... In other words he told me do not do like this: If () { if (){ if() { etc..} } }

Comment: But in your question, If the ModelState.Isvalid = true, model.FullNameIsChecked = false, and model.LookingFor != null, The If condition will be checked for about 12 times. But, using this solution, It will be reduced to 3. 
In your question, if model.IsValid = false, It will go through all the if, else if checks, and the condition will be checked more than 12 times, and finally it will reach else. 
Optimization is not about formatting, but performance tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

erm, this way each condition is checked exactly once.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if (string.IsEmptyOrWhitespace(model.LookingFor))
    {
        model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.UserId == user.Id);
    }
    else
    {
        model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(
                filter: x => x.FullName.Contains(model.LookingFor));
    }

    if(model.FullNameIsChecked)
    {
        model.ContactList.OrderBy(f => f.FullName);
    }
    else
    {
        model.ContactList.OrderBy(e => e.Email); 
    }
}
else
{
    model.ContactList = contactRepository.GetAll(filter: x => x.UserId == user.Id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. The problem is that my mentor says it is bad practice to use more than once If operator within if operator... In other words he told me do not do like this: If () { if (){ if() { etc..} } }

Comment: @StoyanPetkov, well, perhaps your mentor should read the answers here? There is no hard and fast rule in the real world. I'd suggest many `else if`s with compound conditions is worse practice. Its more code and harder to read.

Comment: Okay, but in my kind of position i can't talk him like that... but i get your point and i think you've got point.

Comment: @StoyanPetkov, anyway, I've simplified the code, I don;t think you need to do `OrderBy` in one case and `Sort` in the other.

Comment: Yes, i done that this way just for exercise (different way to do one thing).

Comment: @StoyanPetkov, either you misunderstood your mentor or .. he is wrong. In real life you will have plenty of cases with several nested `if`s. It's **not bad practice**. What he probably mean (guess) is what you you can combine multiple `if` into one (because nested `if` is just another `&&` condition).

Comment: @StoyanPetkov, if you have non functional limitations, like you mentor's whims, you need to state them in the question.

Comment: @Jodrell okay i will do this in feature. Thanks.